# Comparing 2 columns in 2 sheets but filters apple from pineapple like snake from rattlesnake

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have the code below which I basically created before my friend used it here. The only difference is that my code uses animals while his uses fruits. Can anyone advice me how to filter lets say snake from rattlesnake and apple from pineapple because using the fruits he detects apple from pineapple. Here's my code. Kindly advice, If my question is a mess kindly aske me So I can make it clearer. Sorry for my english.

```
Sub lookup()
Dim TotalRows As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

'Copy lookup values from sheet1 to sheet3
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
TotalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Range("A1:A" & TotalRows).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")

'Go to the destination sheet
Sheets("Sheet3").Select

For i = 1 To TotalRows
'Search for the value on sheet2
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 1).Value)
'If it is found put its value on the destination sheet
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    Cells(i, 2).Value = rng.Value
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Need help. Thanks.

Comment: In the .Find method, you can specify the `LookAt` argument to be `xlWhole` for an exact match (not case sensitive) or `xlPart` for a partical match.

Comment: Like This one Sir? `Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 1).Value LookAt:=lPart)` ?? Am I correct or wrng?

Comment: Just missing a comma `Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 1).Value, LookAt:=lPart)`

Comment: @ tigeravatar What if I'm compareing ABC:pineapple and pineapple. This will also get the apple result.

Comment: If you don't want partial matches, use the `xlWhole` operator instead of `xlPart`

Comment: Whenever I search for apple it also grabs the ABC:pineapple Sir. Any idea? Anyways thanks for the lookat function.

Comment: Thank for the help tiger. I found a way to just replace the value from snake to snakes so that it will grab the exact word.

Comment: @Patrick If you found a solution to your own question, pls post it as an answer yourself and accept it as a solution. That way people who come across your question with the same problem will find your solution easily. Also your question won't pop up in the 'unanswered' list anymore.

Comment: Actually what I did is to replace the apple with apples. I used this kind of code `Dim cl As Range For Each cl In Range ("Q10:Q1000") If cl Like "apple" Then cl = "apples" End if Next cl` Hope it does help other people. By the way thanks Yohsoog for the heads up.

Comment: @Patrick not to keep bothering you, but what I meant was to write it out as an actual answer (not a comment). That way you can also accept it as an answer and it'll be obvious for others who might not read the comments.

Comment: oh Sorry. I'll get it done.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem

I just searched for the apple then turned it to apples to be more unique.

Here's the code

```
Dim cl As Range 

For Each cl In Range ("Q10:Q1000") 
  If cl Like "apple" Then 
    cl = "apples"   
  End if 
Next cl
```